# Distance between a function such that $|\int_0 ^1f| < 1$ and a set of functios.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $A=\{f\in C[0,1]\mid f(0)=0\}$, $B=\{f\in A \mid \int_0 ^1f=0\}$ with the $||\cdot ||_\infty $ norm . I showd that if $||f||_\infty =1$ then for $f\in A$ then $|\int_0 ^1f|<1$. Now I need to show that for such $f$ that $d(f,B)=|\int_0 ^1f|$.

I have been working on it for quite a while. I understand how I can find $g\in B$ such that $||f-g||_\infty=|\int_0 ^1f|$ (at least I can draw one), so $d(f,B)\le |\int_0 ^1f|$. But how do I show that $d(f,B)\ge |\int_0 ^1f|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the construction that follows, let $C := \{f\in C[0,1]:\ \int_0^1 f = 0\}$.

It is easy to verify that, given $f\in A$, the distance $d(f, C)$ is attained by the function
$$
g(x) := f(x) - \int_0^1 f,
$$
i.e.
$$
d(f,C) = \left| \int_0^1 f\right|.
$$
Unfortunately, this function $g$ does not belong (in general) to $B$, hence it cannot be used to estimate $d(f, B)$.

On the other hand, $g$ can be approximated in the following way.
Given $\epsilon \in (0, 1/2)$, let $h_\epsilon\in C[0,1]$ be the function defined by
$$
h_\epsilon(x) :=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)} x, &\text{if}\ x\in [0,\epsilon],\\
\dfrac{1}{1-\epsilon}, & \text{if}\ x \in (\epsilon, 1-\epsilon),\\
\dfrac{1}{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)} (1-x), &\text{if}\ x\in [1-\epsilon,1],
\end{cases}
$$
so that $h_\epsilon\in A$, $h_\epsilon\geq 0$, $\int_0^1 h_\epsilon = 1$, $\max h_\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{1-\epsilon}$.

Let us define
$$
g_\epsilon(x) := f(x) - h_\epsilon(x) \int_0^1 f.
$$
We have that $g_\epsilon \in B$ and
$$
d(f, B) \leq \|f-g_\epsilon\|_\infty
= \max h_\epsilon \left| \int_0^1 f\right| 
= \frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \left| \int_0^1 f\right|. 
$$
On the other hand, $d(f,B) \geq d(f,C) = \left|\int_0^1 f\right|$, hence the result follows by taking $\epsilon\to 0$.